# ParallelSaveError with a single call of save() in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am getting a ParrellelSaveError from Mongoose when I try to save a document that has been updated. The issue is that save is only running once, so I don't see how I could have this problem. Everything is working properly, it just throws an error. Here is the code:

Route to update/save user data:

```
update: function(req, res){
    userLogic.updateUser(res.locals.user, req.body)
        .save()
        .then((user)=>{
            return res.redirect("/user/account");
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            console.error(err);
            req.session.toaster = "error";
            req.session.toastMessage = "ERROR: unable to update user data";
            return res.redirect("/user/account");
        });
},
```

userLogic.updateUser() function:

```
updateUser: function(user, data){
    if(!data) throw new SyntaxError("arguments");
    if(!user) throw new TypeError("user");
    email = data.email.toLowerCase();
    if(!isValidEmail(email)) throw new SyntaxError("invalid email");

    user.name = data.name;
    user.email = email;
    user.country = data.country;
    user.address = data.address;

    return user;
}
```

What is causing this error? Why am I getting it when only one save operation is occurring and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are getting a `ParallelSaveError` from Mongoose when you try to save a document that has been updated. This error typically occurs when multiple save operations are executed concurrently on the same document.

To resolve this issue, you can use the `findByIdAndUpdate` function provided by Mongoose instead of updating the document and then saving it. This way, Mongoose will handle updating and saving the document internally, reducing the likelihood of encountering a `ParallelSaveError`.

Here's an updated version of your `updateUser` function:

```js
updateUser: async function(user, data) {
  if (!data) throw new SyntaxError("arguments");
  if (!user) throw new TypeError("user");
  const email = data.email.toLowerCase();
  if (!isValidEmail(email)) throw new SyntaxError("invalid email");

  const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
    user._id,
    {
      name: data.name,
      email: email,
      country: data.country,
      address: data.address
    },
    { new: true }
  );

  return updatedUser;
}
```

Route to update/save user data:

```js
update: async function(req, res) {
  try {
    const user = await userLogic.updateUser(res.locals.user, req.body);
    res.redirect("/user/account");
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    req.session.toaster = "error";
    req.session.toastMessage = "ERROR: unable to update user data";
    res.redirect("/user/account");
  }
}
```

Comment: So how am I getting a parallel save error? There is only one save operation occuring.

Comment: Also, I don't want to run database operations in the logic.